# php checkin if username and password are correct from .txt file

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I have a users.txt file with usernames and passwords stored in this format (for educational purposes it has to be in a .txt file): 
username1:password1 
username2:password2

Passwords are encrypted with md5. I also have a login page where user types in username and password. My question is, how do I check if username and password that the user enters are correct?

Comment: Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: MD5 is not encryption, it is a weak cryptographic hash. A cryptographic hash is a one-way function, it is not possible to reverse the operation. Encryption is a reversible function and had a key which is required to encrypt and decrypt.

Comment: I started learning PHP very recently. The project is for educational purposes as I wrote, and it will not be used in a live environment. I looked online for a solution but was unable to find one, so I'm asking the question here.

Comment: Security is not important for this project since it will not be used anywhere except on my WAMP server for learning. I just need to know how to check if the username and password that a user enters are correct.

Comment: It is easy to handle passwords securely in PHP, there is no ereal reason not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php
$user_input = $_POST['user'];
$password_input = md5($_POST['pass']);

$file = fopen('users.txt', 'r');

while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    list($user, $password) = explode(':', $line);
    if(trim($user) == $user_input && trim($password) == $password_input){
        echo 'Logged in';
        break;
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

With this code your file will be readed line by line, in each line user and password are obtained by this code: `list($user, $password) = explode(':', $line);` and then the code will check if they're equal to the user input. If the user and password are correct, then you get a `Logged in message` and the file is closed.

Comment: Works perfectly if the username and password are correct, but if the username or password are incorrect I get an error. How do I show a message that username or password is incorrect?

Comment: @bux *"How do I show a message that username or password is incorrect?"* Honestly; `if/else`

Comment: @bux supposing usernames are unique, you can add an elseif condition to the if inside the while: `elseif(trim($user) == $user_input){
        echo 'Username/password is incorrect';
        break;
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Passwords should be saved with a non-reversible method for security. When a password needs to be saved it is encoded with non-reversible function and stored. When a password needs to be verified it is again encoded with non-reversible function and that result is compared to the stored version.

In PHP it is easy, just use `password_hash` when storing the password and `password_verify` when verifying a password. This is a very secure method.